# Minikube restarts forever

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have an issue. I typed the `minikube start` command and it stuck. What should I do? Is deleting minikube the only solution?

```
Restarting existing docker container for "minikube"
```

Comment: Which version of Minikube and Kubernetes did you use? Where did you execute the command `minikube start`? Which base OS did you use? [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8209) you can find similar topic on github with the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `sudo minikube delete` to delete the container first,
then `minikube start` and see if the issue is fixed or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided too little information to conclusively solve your problem. But one way is to actually delete the minikube and restart. You can see this [similar question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13712/minikube-for-ubuntu-20-04-wsl-stuck-on-restarting-existing-docker-container-for). Make sure that you have proper privileges to run docker containers.

Generally, this problem occurs quite often on Ubuntu. You can find very extensive [thread on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8209).

In addition to the `Restarting existing docker container for "minikube"`, you should also get some other information (like specific error). If they are insufficient, you can always open an issue on github.

In the thread above you can find a couple of potential solutions. Here is one of them:

> When I run  `minikube --start --driver=docker --alsologtostderr`, I get the same error message with "no such file or directory".
>
> Edit: I was able to fix this by changing to .deb docker instead of snap docker.
>
> Per  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/:
> "If you're using the none driver in Debian or a derivative, use the .deb packages for Docker rather than the snap package, which does not work with Minikube. You can download .deb packages from Docker."
>
> I did  `$ snap remove docker`, then followed these instructions:
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository
>
> Maybe the error messages could be amended to tell this to the user?